# I put my try catch in a do while loop, but the commands after the do-while loop continue running even though there is an exception caught

Tags: java, validation, if-statement, try-catch, do-while

I'm building a small program that checks if the user input is a number. The program runs but when my catch block catches an exception, it somehow exited the nested do-while loop it is in.

Here's my program :

```
package TESTCLASS;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Apples {
    
    static int readValidInt(Scanner in, String prompt, int min,  int max){
            
        int validUserInput;
        int userInput = 0; //have to initialize this variable since I will be using it in a block, setting it to 0 for now
        int checker =1;

        while(!in.hasNextInt()) { //Makes sure that user inputs an Integer, not String, double, etc
            System.out.println("Sorry, only numbers in integer form is allowed. Please enter your choice as an integer between 1 and 4");
            in.next();
        }
        do {
            
            do {
                try {
                    userInput = in.nextInt();
                        checker = 0;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception detectedddd");
                    in.nextLine(); // This line is to *clear the buffer* for Scanner
                }
            }while (checker ==1 );
    
            if ( userInput >= min && userInput <= max) {
                        System.out.println("you have chosen board " + userInput );
                        validUserInput = userInput;
                    }
            else {
                System.out.println(prompt);
                validUserInput = 0;
                
                 }  
        }while (validUserInput==0);
        
        return validUserInput;
    }
    
    // Main function
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choose a board style");
        
        readValidInt(input, "Bruh that's not valid", 1, 4);     
    }

}
```

Here is my output(As you can see, when I put "five", two things get printed out - "Exception detectedddd" & "Bruh that's not valid", but the latter sentence is part of the if else statement, which should not have been reached since there is an exception :

Choose a board style

100

Bruh that's not valid

five

Exception detectedddd

Bruh that's not valid

six

Exception detectedddd

Bruh that's not valid

10

Bruh that's not valid

1

you have chosen board 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first input (100) you set `checker = 0;`. Since the value is too large you print "Bruh that's not valid" and stay within the outer loop.

That means that you read another value (five) which leads to the exception. However, since `checker` is already 0 (from the first pass) the inner loop is not repeated.

You need to reset `checker` to 1 before each start of the inner loop:

```
    do {

        checker = 1;            
        do {
            try {
                userInput = in.nextInt();
                checker = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception detectedddd");
                in.nextLine(); // This line is to *clear the buffer* for Scanner
            }
        } while (checker == 1);

        //... remainder of the outer loop
    } while (validUserInput == 0);
```

Comment: wow thank you . That was some inception loop inside loop inside loop thingy. Couldn't have seen that mistake at all.